# Java, Android, Socket. Простой клиент

Tags: java, android, сокет

Хочу написать простой Android клиент.

Сервер на Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7575);
        System.out.println("Wait");
        ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Ok");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader();
}
```

Клиент на Android:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button b01;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
           Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",7575);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        b01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Приложение крашиться. Почему? Отладку по usb не могу посмотреть, потому что телефон китайский.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - есть жи localhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Нельзя проводить операции с сетью в главном потоке.
Попробуйте использовать `AsyncTask` (в дальнейшем изучите тему и не используйте `AsyncTask` для сетевых операций, есть пути лучше и безопаснее, но сложнее)

```
private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

      \\здесь выполняйте обращение к серверу

        return null;
    }
}
```

Запускать так

```
new ConnectTask().execute();
```

И когда приложение крашится, выкладывайте стэк-трэйс